# What is a 'mover' in molecular dynamics?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, reference-request

- [Movers](https://www.rosettacommons.org/docs/latest/scripting_documentation/RosettaScripts/Movers/Movers-RosettaScripts)

What is a 'mover' in molecular dynamics?

Can you supply me with reading material on 'mover'?

Comment: I think this term is specific to the RosettaScripts program you linked to. It took me a bit of searching, but I did find a [summary page](https://www.rosettacommons.org/docs/latest/rosetta_basics/structural_concepts/Mover) on their site that explains generally what a mover is.

Comment: I gave my +1 a long time ago, but did the comment by Tyberius answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link provided by Tyberius](https://www.rosettacommons.org/docs/latest/rosetta_basics/structural_concepts/Mover) in a comment explains what a mover is.

If someone would like to explain it here, I can delete this Community Wiki answer (you can just ask me in a comment on this answer, or click "flag" and "In need of moderator intervention" and explain yourself).